# I'm trying to get first 3 results from MySQL database in Node.js and I'm getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here's the code I'm using

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM tables', function(err, results) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log(results[0].rawname)
                for(var i= 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                    eval("var " + 'name_' + i + ' = ' + "'" + results[i].rawname + "'" + ";")
                    eval("var " + 'url_' + i + ' = ' + "'" + results[i].url + "'" + ";")
                    eval("var " + 'creator_' + i + ' = ' + "'" + results[i].creator + "'" + ';' )
                }
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rawname' of undefined

Now I know it's a problem with the `i` variable since I tried logging it outside the loop with a 0 in the place of the `i` and it seems to work fine, how can I do it with the `i` variable?

Comment: dont use eval else can do arbitrary code injection: `evil'; process.exit();//` instead simply use `var name = results[i].rawname` dont need the `_1`

Comment: then if i want to use results[1] then i will have to create a new var names name1 or name2 cuz im only saving it once

Comment: just use `results` no need to loop just to set variables

Comment: the whole point is to avoid setting 9 variables, sure i can just got like `name1 = results[0].rawname` and copy paste it like 2 more times and do the same for url and creator but the point was to make it clean, also what you said about the `process.exit();`, that can never happen since non of these values are allowed to have any symbols (except ofc the url but that will never contain anything like that)

Answer (score 0):

You are counting from zero till 3 included. So you try to loop over 4 results instead of the intended 3 results.

Answer (score -1):

so the problem was not in the js but in the table, so the thing is there was no results[1] since i only had 1 result, well, sorry for wasting your time.